# Date format in queryset lookups

Tags: python, django, validation, web, django-queryset

I'm trying to retrieve information by weekday using querysets in Django, but if I use the week_day look up I get this error:

```
Exception Type: NotImplementedError Exception Value: subclasses of BaseDatabaseOperations may require a date_extract_sql() method
```

I tried different ways of getting the week day:

```
sun_data = week.annotate(weekday=ExtractWeekDay('date_in'))\
        .values('weekday')\
        .annotate(c=Sum('data'))\
        .values('weekday', 'c')
```

and

```
 mon_data = week.filter(date_in__week_day=2)
```

But I haven't had luck with any solution I have wrote.

Hope you can help me! :)

Comment: What database are you using? The problem sounds like you're using an unsupported database for that annotation class.

Comment: I'm using Mongodb

Comment: Then that's likely the problem. The connection wrapper for MongoDB doesn't support that annotation. You might be able to implement it yourself using `dayOfWeek`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek/